# BULK INSERT Incorrect syntax near 'BULK'. / BCP pushing to prod instead of dev

Tags: sql-server, ssms, bulkinsert, bcp

First problem: I'm new to SSMS and trying to fill an empty table with a csv file:

```
BULK INSERT database.schema.ExpectedValuesBASE
FROM 'bla\bla\bla\output_teaching.csv'
WITH
    (
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
        TABLOCK
    );
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error at line: 1, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'BULK'.

Second problem:

```
BCP database.schema.ExpectedValuesBASE in blah/bla/output.csv -S DEVSERVERNAME -U ******** -P ****** -t ',' -q -c
```

This is writing the values to the production server, rather than the specified `DEVSERVERNAME`

Answer (score 0):

This query uses bulk insert to store the file in a #temptable and then inserts the contents from this temp table into the table you want in the database.

```
 CREATE TABLE #temptable (col1,col2,col3)
 BULK INSERT #temptable from 'C:\yourfilelocation\yourfile.csv' 
 WITH 
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2, 
    fieldterminator = ',', 
    rowterminator = '0x0A' 
    ) `


INSERT INTO yourTableInDataBase (col1,col2,col3)
SELECT (col1,col2,col3)
FROM #temptable
```

You can either execute query above in SQL Server, or  you can put it inside a stored procedure and call the stored procedure using batch. copy the following code and put this inside textfile and save as `.cmd` extension and run.

```
set MYDB= yourDBname
set MYUSER=youruser
set MYPASSWORD=yourpassword
set MYSERVER=yourservername
sqlcmd -S %MYSERVER% -d %MYDB% -U %MYUSER% -P %MYPASSWORD% -h -1 -s "," -W -Q "exec yourstoredprocedure"
```

Comment: When I execute the above query I get the same error Parse error at line: 9, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'BULK'

Comment: Make sure the columns name in the temptable (col1, col2, col3) are the same name and format (varchar, int etc) as the columns you are trying to import.